# Как в Java передать переменную из одного onClick в другой?

Tags: java, android, строки, android-dialog, android-on-click

Делаю AlertDialog со списком. Нужно передать переменную, создаваемую при нажатии на пункт из списка, в метод onClick, вызывающийся при нажатии на кнопку закрытия диалога. HELP!

код:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(pay, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            String what = pay.getItem(which);

        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //использовать what
            dialog.cancel();


        }
    });
```

Comment: @post_zeew, тогда надо на оба события повесить один и тот же его экземпляр.

Comment: @woesss, А, чет я проглядел. Думал, что там в одном интерфейсе два метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое сделать what полем класса.  String what = ""; - в поле класса, это поле будет доступно везде в классе.

Comment: Извините, я не понял - в каком поле класса(это наверное тупой вопрос, я новичок в этом)?

Comment: Разберитесь с основами, есть класс, у класса есть поля и конструкторы, так вот поля класса видны во всем классе их можно изменить (установить новое значение) в одном методе и использовать в другом, как вам и надо.